# Print json decoded array

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to print a value from a object array, but I'm facing some problems.  I want to echo in php the value of `[title]` but i am not getting it!

```
stdClass Object (
    [result] => success
    [records] => stdClass Object (
        [500272328] => stdClass Object (
            [nif] => 500272328
            [pc4] => 2775
            [pc3] => 372
            [seo_url] => solnave-restaurantes-e-alimentacao-s-a
            [title] => Solnave - Restaurantes e Alimentação S.a
            [city] => Cascais
            [racius] => http://www.racius.com/solnave-restaurantes-e-alimentacao-s-a/
            [portugalio] => http://www.portugalio.com/solnave-restaurantes-e-alimentacao-sa-2/
        )
    )
)
```

How can i retrieve?
Thank you!

Comment: How have you tried to access it?  What errors have you gotten?

Comment: Hi! I tried yes. :) i did echo $json->title and several other ways, including foreach loops and im receiving a lot of blank pages.

Comment: Does `echo $yourOBJ->records->500272328->title;` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `stdClass` is a PHP object or a Javascript encoded object?

It seems a PHP, so to echo `title`  element you must navigate at there:

```
       echo $yourobjarray->records->500272328->title;
```

or

```
       echo $yourobjarray->records->500272328['title'];
```

(not evident in your question)

But to echo into  `<script>` section of a HTML page,

```
  <script> ... 
      var x='<?=  $yourobjarray->records->500272328['title'];?>'; 
  ...</script>
```

and, if a AJAX context, to JSON response you need

```
  echo json_encode($x);
```

where $x is your array or the title string, or what you want.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you are calling `json_decode` to decode the JSON string.

You should call it as `json_decode($thestring_to_be_decoded, true)`. This will convert the objects to associative arrays and you will be able to access the title field.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of a `foreach` construct to loop through your JSON decoded object array or If you want to print individual elements you can simply do like this.

```
echo $yourobjarray->result; //"prints" success
```